# Counting argument for $\sum \frac{\sigma}{n}$

Tags: number-theory

WTS $\sum_{n \leq x } \frac {\sigma(n)}{n} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}x + O(\log (x)) $

First we have that $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\sigma (n)}{n} = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n} \sigma (n)= \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{d|n} d  $ we now flip the sums;  $\sum_{d\leq x} d  \sum_{n \leq x, d|n} \frac{1}{n} =\sum_{d\leq x}   \sum_{n \leq x, d|n} \frac{d}{n} $

We notice that $ d|n \iff \frac{n}{d}|n $ so we may replace $\frac {d}{n} $ with $\frac{\frac{n}{d}}{n} = \frac {1}{d}$ it follows that $\sum_{d\leq x}   \sum_{n \leq x, d|n} \frac{d}{n} =\sum_{d\leq x}   \sum_{n \leq x, d|n} \frac{1}{d}= \sum_{d\leq x} \frac{1}{d}  \sum_{n \leq x, d|n} 1 =\sum_{d\leq x} \frac{1}{d}  \lfloor \frac {x}{d}\rfloor $ but we see that d is a dummy variable so it follows that  $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\sigma (n)}{n} = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor $

From here we have that $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{x}{n^2}  + O(1) = x \sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}  + \sum_{n \leq x} O(1) - \sum_{x}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x} =  x \space \zeta(2)  + \sum_{n \leq x} O(1) - O(\log (x))$ 
It follows that   $x \frac{\pi^2}{6}  + \sum_{n \leq x} O(1) + O(\log (x))$ but something wrongs as it appears that $\sum_{n \leq x} O(1) $ is $O(x)$ which is not what i want.

Comment: Note the difference between $\frac{1}{n}\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\rfloor$ and $\frac{x}{n^2}$ is at most $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get
an explicit bound on
the error term.

Since
$\frac{x}{n}-1
\le \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor
\le \frac{x}{n}$,

$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor
\le \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n}  \frac{x}{n}
= x\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^2} 
$

and

$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor
\ge \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n}  (\frac{x}{n}-1)
= x\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^2} -\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} 
= x\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^2} -\ln(x)+O(1)
$

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just getting your notation a bit mixed up at the end.  You say 
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{x}{n^2}  + O(1)$$  I think you want the $O(1)$ under the summation sign:

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x}{n}  + O(1)\right)$$

and from there on, it looks like plain sailing.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \ldots = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{x}{n^2} + O(1)$$

but this should be

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \left[ \frac{x}{n} + O(1) \right] = x \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^2} + O(1) \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n}$$

You can probably take it from there.